# Getting Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes error while running test cases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, mockito

I'm using Java 11. Tried almost everything, still it's not working. Done Invalidate Cache & restart as well.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the dependencies, I've added in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>*emphasized text*
```

This is the class which is mocking and it's not able to mock, I've some test cases for the UserService.

This is UserServiceImpltest.java

```
package com.stackroute.keepnote.test.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.stackroute.keepnote.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.stackroute.keepnote.service.UserServiceImpl;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import com.stackroute.keepnote.exceptions.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.stackroute.keepnote.model.User;
import com.stackroute.keepnote.repository.UserRepository;



public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;


    User user;

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    List<User> userList = null;
    Optional<User> options;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        user = new User();
        user.setUserAddedDate(new Date());
        user.setUserId("John123");
        user.setUserMobile("1234567789");
        user.setUserName("john");
        user.setUserPassword("johnpass");
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.add(user);

        options = Optional.of(user);

    }
```

This is the User class, which is declare public
@Document
public class User {

```
/*
 * This class should have five fields (userId,userName,
 * userPassword,userMobile,userAddedDate). Out of these five fields, the field
 * userId should be annotated with @Id (This annotation explicitly specifies the document
 * identifier). This class should also contain the getters and setters for the
 * fields, along with the no-arg , parameterized constructor and toString
 * method.The value of userAddedDate should not be accepted from the user but
 * should be always initialized with the system date.
 */

@Id
private String userId;
private String userName;
private String userPassword;
private String userMobile;
private Date userAddedDate;

public User() {
}

public User(String userId, String userName, String userPassword, String userMobile, Date userAddedDate) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    this.userMobile = userMobile;
    this.userAddedDate = userAddedDate;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public String getUserMobile() {
    return userMobile;
}

public void setUserMobile(String userMobile) {
    this.userMobile = userMobile;
}

public void setUserAddedDate(Date userAddedDate) {
    this.userAddedDate = userAddedDate;
}
```

Comment: First you are mixing things. mockito-core is the one you need. the mockito-all is wrong. Why have you added asm? Furthermore do not add images better put the text as text in the post... (see also https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Declaring-mockito-dependency)

Comment: Remove mockito-all & asm as well. Still getting error like this:

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Failed to release mocks

This should not happen unless you are using a third-part mock maker

Comment: Please show the class where you are using the mock and the class you are trying to mock...

Comment: Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.stackroute.keepnote.repository.UserRepository.                                   @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {


}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your "Failed to release mocks" comment, my guess is that you have an older version of the spring-boot-starter-test dependency. If you're not able to update your spring boot version, you can update mockito and byte-buddy, either in `<dependencies>` or `<dependencyManagement>`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.28</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I started seeing that "Failed to release mocks" error when I upgraded to Java SE 15:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Failed to release mocks

This should not happen unless you are using a third-part mock maker
```

At the bottom of the stack trace, here's the clue that it's an outdated byte-buddy problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Java version: 15
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion.ofJavaVersion(ClassFileVersion.java:232)
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion$VersionLocator$ForJava9CapableVm.locate(ClassFileVersion.java:485)
```

The version of spring-boot-starter-test that I am using has outdated mockito and byte-buddy dependencies that aren't aware of the more recent Java releases. Updating the dependencies should clear up your problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me in a JpaDataTest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring boot, you need to remove all other dependencies (mockito, asm, jaxb-api). This starter `spring-boot-starter-test` make sure everything you need for your test are already there with the correct version. You can check the pom [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.3.3.RELEASE/jar).

Comment: Earlier I tried using this only, but I thought that the error is because of mockito. It wasn't working that way as well

Comment: Make sure your User class is not final and not private (not sure what is private class maybe private inner class) otherwise Mockito can't create a proxy to mock your class

Comment: It's public, I've added that in my question as well.